# Rename namespace in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, renaming

I had a collection of classes and forms that I have since re-organised into folders. I thought I should rename the namespaces to match the folder structure, but now I have a whole heap of errors like

> The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context.

What is the proper process to rename a namespace in Visual Studio (2010)

Comment: so you want VS to code for you?? or to assist you?? VS already have feature which assist you to rename the namespaces..  put the cursor at the end of the line defining namespce for that particular class. and press "Ctrl+." it will show the context meny type suggest saying to rename the namespace to match with folder structure.. select that.. it will name the namespace as per structure.. but only for that class or cs file only..

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm not sure you finished that properly, "Ctrl+" looks like half a shortcut input, like "Ctrl+I" for example. And "Ctrl" and "+" don't do anything...

Comment: man check properly I wrote **" Ctrl + ."**  notice dot is here after control

Comment: Oh sorry. The text is so small I didn't even see the "."

Comment: not an issue.. it happens.. and yeah if you have installed some tools like reSharper it may overwrite the existing shortcut.. if you have installed it.. try **"Alt + <Enter>"**

Comment: Unfortunately the "Ctrl + ." isn't working. And I don't have re-sharper.

Comment: try this if it works for you.. sorry I don't have 2010, working on 2013 :D 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174193/visual-studio-is-there-a-move-class-to-different-namespace-refactoring#answer-3360343