# Updating the namespace automatically in Visual Studio 2015/ C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, refactoring

I am doing some clean up/ restructuring on my code (C#) were I move my classes in the tree structure. I am looking for a way to update all namespaces to the default ones (like projectname.rootFolder.ChildFolder).

I know that there are some ways to do it one by one like in this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174193/visual-studio-is-there-a-move-class-to-different-namespace-refactoring) but I am looking for a clean simple update way. I wish there was something like "right clicking on the folder and clicking on update namespace!" but there is not.

Anyone knows any add-on/ easy way to do it?

Comment: Use [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: @Murtoza thanks for the help it worked fine

Comment: @Murtoza would you like to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a tool to work on legacy code. Try to use this tool.
Right click on the folder> go to refactor and then select adjust Namespaces

[image]