# visual studio 2019 move c# class to a new file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, refactoring, shortcut

for a better organization of the project I have a class file in a separate directory (same project folder ofc). when i create a new class inside a class file that is in the root directory of the project, i'm able to use "move to new file" option, but when the class is located in another directory i don't have that option.
a solution would be to do it manually but i think it's not very clean when the project gets bigger

**in short words:**
i'm only able to move the class if the classfile is in the root directory of the project
is there a way to make it possible from all subfolders of the project ?

Comment: See the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55782663/5509738). If you are performing this action a lot, consider looking at Resharper which has this functionality and more like adjusting namespaces after moving files from one folder to another folder.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I require that functionality often. for the time being i can't afford Reshaper so i will either look for a free alternative or keep doing that manually by creating the class inside the main then moving it to subdirectories