# Automatically add a "using" to all files with a given reference (C# in Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

My C#, .NET 6 project has a namespace that contains multiple classes. I'm moving one of the classes, but not the others, to a new namespace. Is there a way to have Visual Studio automatically add a `using` for the new namespace to all the files that contain reference to that class, rather than doing it individually file by file?

Comment: Visual Studio has a ["Move type to namespace" refactoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/move-type-to-namespace?view=vs-2019) but it's not clear it will do everything you need. Resharper has a ["Move Type to Another Namespace refactoring"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_Namespace.html) that will update usages. C# 10 supports a [`global` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier) for `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have summarized three methods that may be helpful to your issue:

1. When moving classes, use [Move type to namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/move-type-to-namespace?view=vs-%202019) that comes with Visual Studio

You can right-click the class you want to move and click `Quick Actions and Refactorings`, then click `Move type to namespace`. This way you can choose into which namespace to move the class.

However, in my testing, I found that this function can easily disrupt your original layout and cause multiple namespaces to appear in a cs file.

2. global using `your namespace`

Just add `global` before you introduce the namespace, so no matter how you move the class, you don't need to change your namespace.

For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier

3. Use some tools

For details, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/175613/20528460

Answer (score 2):

You can also prefix the 'using' directive with 'global' to avoid importing the same directive in every file. The directive will now apply to all files in the project or compilation unit.